# Sort array as number but not string in powershell

Tags: powershell

Would like to convert a string with collection of numbers into a sorted array object in PowerShell. However, it was sorted based on the ASCII value of each character, but not the value of number. For example: I have

```
[string]$PortException = "3128,53,3389,5985,5986"
```

When sort with Sort-Object:

```
$PortExceptionArray = ($PortException.Split(',') | Sort-Object)
```

The outcome to the array is in the order of:

```
3128
3389
53
5985
5986
```

However, it is expect that "53" will be on the top.

Any thoguht?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **cast** the string to an **integer**:

```
$PortExceptionArray = $PortException -split ',' | Sort-Object -Property {[int]$_ }
```

**Output:**

```
53
3128
3389
5985
5986
```

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot for the quick answer:)

Comment: Or for short: `[int[]]$PortException.Split(',') | Sort-Object`